# Is there a way to restrict who can manage lambda aliases

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm actively looking around to see if there's a way to restrict which AWS users can manage aliases on lambda methods. One of the projects I'm adjacent to stages their lambda methods with aliases, which requires us to add specialized permissions to the associated API Gateway. These permissions need to be added through the CLI. Since this isn't very intuitive, we would like to see if we can make sure that our production aliases can only be managed by specific people.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but what I've previously done is set an authorizer for a lambda function with Api event that has aliases (dev, stage, prod), see the `auth` property https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-api.html. For example, with `AWS_IAM` authorizer only a specific role can make the request to the lambda.

Comment: I don't think this would apply in this case. As you said, `auth` manages who can make requests to the lambda method. I'm looking to manage who can make changes to the lambda method's aliases. This is more of a "how do I protect our infrastructure" question.